# How to config qmake generating Visual Studio solution using directory-structure for source files in projects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, qmake

I would like to create a Visual Studio project with qmake out of a makefile. So far that works fine with `qmake AllProjects.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2013 -tp vc "CONFIG+=debug_and_release" -o %CD%/$(VC13PROJ)/AllProjects.sln`. The problem is, that every project has it's header and source-filters with those files plain at top level. I'm using Qt5.5.1.

But what I like to have is that the files are structured like in the directory, because they are group there logically and giving a better overview on project structure. Is there a possibility to config the qmake using directory-structure instead of putting all files plain at top-level?

Directory structure:

```
source/
  dir1/  
    file1.h
    file1.cpp
  dir2/
    file2.h
    file2.cpp
```

Problem: Project structure in Visual Studio, looks like:

```
project/
  header/  
    file1.h
    file1.h
  source/
    file1.cpp
    file2.cpp
```

I would like to have a structure inside Visual Studio like:

```
project/
  header-filter/
    dir1/
      file1.h
    dir2/
      file2.h
  source-filter/
    dir1/
      file1.cpp
    dir2/
      file2.cpp
```

alternative that is also fine:

```
project/
  dir1/  
    file1.h
    file1.cpp
  dir2/
    file2.h
    file2.cpp
```

For something like 30+ files in source and header, getting an overview is difficult if everything is together at top-level.

EDIT: `CONFIG-=flat` as `qmake`-option seems to give a structure relative to the vcxproj-file.

```
project/
  header-filter/
    ../
      ../
        source/
          dir1/
            file1.h
          dir2/
            file2.h
  source-filter/
    ../
      ../
        source/
          dir1/
            file1.cpp
          dir2/
            file2.cpp
```

So the question remains, if it is possible to get rid of the starting relative path:

```
    ../
      ../
        source/
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

I solved the problem by writing a python script parsing the `.vcxproj.filters-files` of the created solution. It searches for the created filter groups replaces them and afterwards adapting the assigned filter groups of all items in a filter.